# 2 Servers for website and media files (Wordpress Plugin Needed)

Tags: wordpress, plugins, overloading

I am needing to host media files on one server (with a different domain name) and have my website (files) on the other. I have all Wordpress base websites and am needing all current files to be moved to the other domain/server. I cannot do this manually as there are over 10,000 media files all up. Is there any plugin that allows to do this? Or any other way to do this? I am doing this to reduce the average CPU load / memory requirement. Thanks

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for ServerFault, but you should look into using Nginx if you're not, and if you are you can easily use it as a reverse proxy for static content.

Comment: Thanks for your support and information

Comment: I don't have a guide for specifically what you are trying to do, but I just happened to write this up about [reverse proxies with nginx](http://justin.ag/technology/nginx-reverse-proxy-legacy-website/).

Comment: Actually, I'll just write something up as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having performance issues with WordPress, my first recommendation would be to make sure you are using a caching plugin such as [WP Super Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/) or [W3 Total Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache) (I happen to use the latter). You will need to use a persistent caching option as well for the best performance, such as [Memcached](http://memcached.org/).

I can only speak to W3TC, but it does have an option to server your static content via a CDN such as [RackSpace CloudFiles](http://tracking.rackspace.com/SHhn). When configured properly it will move files from your media library to the CDN, and replace the links in your content to the proper URL.

If performance is your main interest, you should also look at serving your site via [Nginx](http://nginx.org/) and `php-cgi`, managed through something like [`spawn-fcgi`](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/spawn-fcgi/wiki/WikiStart). There are some caveats to using Nginx vs Apache, but once tuned the performance is far superior. You can find a [guide for the configuration](http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx) on the WordPress site.

Lastly you can set up a reverse proxy from your front end server to point to static files hosted on a different server - the content just passes through your front end server. This can be accomplished using Apache or Nginx, but the performance will be better in the latter. Please see my site for an example of using an [Nginx reverse proxy](http://justinsilver.com/technology/nginx-reverse-proxy-legacy-website/) - you would just want to proxy requests for your static files location to a different back-end server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.